# Draggin Dropping of AVM1(ActionScript 1/2) dont work in AVM2(ActionScript 3/Flex)

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, avm2

I have a application developed in ActionScript 2 which has dragging/dropping activity. which works fine. I used following to test dropping

```
dropObject.hitTest(_root._xmouse, _root._ymouse, true) //if true, drop currently dragging object
```

Problem occurs when I put this SWF in my Flex application SWFLoader container. dragging dosen't work at all in this case.

any ideas guys?

Comment: Could this have anything to do with _root?

when hosted in other VM(Flex container), may be values of property of _root not be same as in normal case...????

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally figured out why it was happening(or not happening!)

When we put AVM1 object in AVM2 container, AVM1 coordinate system goes on a toss. TO prevent it, put a dummy sprite on top-left corner in AVM1 and change all logic of drag-drop checking with respect to that object, and not with _root.

This is not the case with others AVM2 modules though. They work fine standalone and within another container.

Answer (score 1):

no interoperability (such as calling methods or using parameters) between the AVM1Movie object and AVM2 objects is allowed.

taken from:
http://www.adobe.com/livedocs/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/

Comment: But I'm not using any interoperatibility as such or calling any method from one VM to another one. I'm just running a self contained, properly working module into SWFLoader and displaying it.

Comment: I would call dragging interoperability. You're calling the drag & drop method of the AVM1 movie from the AVM2 movie.